# LINQ Convert List of items to Lookup of rows with redundant values

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, mapping, ienumerable

I believe the title doesn't help much, I'll try to explain better here... and hopefully you can help me.

I have this class

```
public class ItemValue
{
    public string SetId {get; set;}
    public string ItemId {get; set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}
}
```

And I have a collection of objects of this class like this one

```
IEnumerable<ItemValue> = new List<ItemValue>()
{
    new ItemValue
    {
        SetId = "S1",
        ItemId = "I1",
        Value = "S1I1V",
    },
    new ItemValue
    {
        SetId = "S1",
        ItemId = "I2",
        Value = "S1I2V",
    },
    new ItemValue
    {
        SetId = "S1",
        ItemId = "I3",
        Value = "S1I3V",
    },
    new ItemValue
    {
        SetId = "S2",
        ItemId = "I1",
        Value = "S2I1V",
    },
    new ItemValue
    {
        SetId = "S2",
        ItemId = "I2",
        Value = "S2I2V1",
    },
    new ItemValue
    {
        SetId = "S2",
        ItemId = "I2",
        Value = "S2I2V2",
    },
    new ItemValue
    {
        SetId = "S2",
        ItemId = "V3",
        Value = "S2I3V",
    }
};
```

Notice there are 2 instances with `SetId="S2"` and `ItemId="I2"` with different values

What I need is to map this collection to something like this using LINQ

```
var expectedResult = new Lookup<string, IDictionary<string, string>>()
{
    ["S1"] = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
    {
        { ["I1"] = "S1I1V" },
        { ["I2"] = "S1I2V" },
        { ["I3"] = "S1I3V" },
    },
    ["S2"] = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
    {
        { ["I1"] = "S2I1V" },
        { ["I2"] = "S2I2V1" },
        { ["I3"] = "S2I3V" },
    },
    ["S2"] = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
    {
        { ["I1"] = "S2I1V" },
        { ["I2"] = "S2I2V2" },
        { ["I3"] = "S2I3V" },
    }
};
```

I'm not good at LINQ myself and after some unsuccessful LINQ trials and an ugly solution using a bunch of foreach and ifs, I'm now reaching you to please get some ideas for this.

If you need any additional information, please just let me know

Thank you very much in advance!...

Answer (score 1):

you could do something similar with [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-5.0) and ToDictionary/ToLookup

```
        var dict = items.GroupBy(i => i.SetId)
            .ToDictionary(
                group => group.Key,
                group => group.ToLookup(i => i.ItemId, i => i.Value));
         dict["S2"]["I2"].ToList() // usage example
```

An alternative would be

```
var dict2 = items.ToLookup(i => (i.SetId, i.ItemId), i => i.Value);
dict2[("S2", "I2")].ToList() // usage example
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing with this solution is that I don't know if is "I2" who is gonna have 2 (or more) values or "I3" or "I2" and "I3"... so technically I need to replicate the entire Set where there are repeated values, because this will later be a row of an excel file... I believe I should have some "Join" somewhere to do the replication, but so far I've failed miserably... once again thank you :)